# Problems deleting files from bucket using $FILE parameter

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am running a bash script that downloads files into my bucket and runs some analyses before deleting the file from the bucket. I am not able to delete the file again using $FILE, only when using wildcards against the files sharing similar endings.

```
mapfile  -t files < files.txt
echo "${files[@]}"
for FILE in ${files[@]}; do
gsutil -u absolute-bison-xxx cp $FILE gs://bucket
come commands...
gsutil rm gs://bucket/$FILE;
done
```

Then when I run the script the file cannot be deleted from the bucket when using $FILE, but it deletes it if I choose *bam (specifying any file with the same ending)

```
 Copying gs://test.bam...
    / [1 files][ 23.4 GiB/ 23.4 GiB]
    Operation completed over 1 objects/23.4 GiB.
    CommandException: "rm" command does not support "file://" URLs. Did you mean to use a gs:// URL?
```

Comment: I have to specify my project name -u absolute-bison-xxxx

Comment: Quotes will probably help.